# Count e-mails in many different folders using vba for a weekly report

Tags: vba, excel

Still trying to automate a report and part of it is a count of **e-mails** in each folder.

The following MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/folder-showitemcount-property-outlook) works for one folder, but I have close to 100 folders to go through.

New folders are created and old ones deleted throughout the course of the week.

**Is there a way to pull the names of the folders and count the e-mails that have been received during the week?**

```
Sub ShowTotalItemCount() 
 Dim nmsName As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim fldFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set nmsName = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set fldFolder = nmsName.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
 fldFolder.ShowItemCount = olShowUnreadItemCount 
End Sub
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at a code below. I have used solution proposed in this website: http://vbatools.pl/lista-folderow-outlooka/ and changed it a bit to get also items count. This Sub call itself if there are nested folders in subfolders. Works fine for me. I'm using sth like this for my own reports.

If you uncomment line: " ' Debug.Print Fold.Name, " etc you will get the list of your folders and subfolders. 
If you add comment to "Call ListItemsFromLastWeek(Fold)" items from last week won't be counted. Instead you will get full report of all items in each folders (as previously mentioned debug suggest).

```
Option Explicit

Sub OutlookFolders()

    Dim olNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folders
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNamespace.Folders
    For Each objFolder In olFolder
      Debug.Print objFolder.Name
      Call LoopFolders(objFolder.Folders)    
    Next objFolder

    Set olNamespace = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub LoopFolders(Folders As Outlook.Folders)

  Dim Fold As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  For Each Fold In Folders
   ' Debug.Print Fold.Name, Fold.Folders.Count, Fold.UnReadItemCount, 
  Fold.Items.Count, Fold.Parent ', Fold.FolderPath
    Call ListItemsFromLastWeek(Fold)
    DoEvents
    If Fold.Folders.Count Then LoopFolders Fold.Folders

  Next Fold

End Sub

Private Sub ListItemsFromLastWeek(Folder As Outlook.Folder)

  Dim item As MailItem
  Dim HowManyDays As Integer
  Dim counter As Long

  HowManyDays = 7

   For Each item In Folder.Items
    If item.ReceivedTime > Now - HowManyDays Then
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
  Next item
  Debug.Print "In folder: " & Folder.Name & "  - there are " & counter & " 
 mails received in the past week (it means from " & Now - HowManyDays & " )"
End Sub
```

Comment: hi 1001001, in the LoopFolders sub, I am receiving a compile error "Invalid use of property" highlighting the .Count in "Fold.Items.Count".

Comment: In this contstruction as above you will get this error. Move this:

     Debug.Print Fold.Name, Fold.Folders.Count, 
     Fold.UnReadItemCount, 
     Fold.Items.Count, Fold.Parent ', Fold.FolderPath

To one line as part of debug.print expression.

Also make sure that last Debug.print is in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example that will get you started:

```
Sub ShowTotalItemCount()
    Dim nmsName As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim fldFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim fldSubFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim itmMail As MailItem
    Dim ItemCount As Long

    Set nmsName = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fldFolder = nmsName.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    For Each fldSubFolder In fldFolder.Folders
        ItemCount = 0
        Debug.Print fldSubFolder.Name
        For Each itmMail In fldSubFolder.Items
            If itmMail.ReceivedTime > Now - 7 Then
                ItemCount = ItemCount + 1
            End If
        Next
        Debug.Print "  No of mails: " & fldSubFolder.Items.Count
        Debug.Print "  No of mails last 7 days: " & ItemCount
    Next

End Sub
```

It checks the ReceivedTime field of the mail item and if it is newer than 7 days it is counted. If you have other items in your folders, it will need some tweaking.